# Scheduling tasks to minimize the total number of utilized cores

Tags: linear-programming, reference-request, scheduling, robust-optimization

I currently have a scheduling algorithm which computes an approximate solution, say S, for the nominal scenario of a given problem instance, say N. Given that N changes in a way and becomes infeasible, I want to reuse S and complement it in a way so that:

1. The method is able to compute a solution (by relaxing some of the constraints)
2. The new solution violates a minimum amount of constraints.

The new problem essentially becomes the following: We have a set of tasks, each task with release time, deadline, duration, and a set of time slots. We can assign tasks to run in parallel and they are pre-emptible. Objective is to assign the tasks in a way that minimizes the total number of cores used.

Is someone aware of such scheduling problem in the literature or any suggestions how to address it?

Comment: What constraint violations would you allow? Early release? Late completion? Not performing a task at all?

Comment: @prubin I have send you an email

Comment: I have not received it. I any case, it would be better to edit the question to clarify what  constraint violations you have in mind.

Comment: @prubin you allow for more tasks to be scheduled in parallel and essentially becomes the problem I’ve mentioned above. I seek a good approximate approach (quicker than a IP)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a job scheduling problem. So say set of Tasks, $Z$, Time slots/cores $ T$. Define a continuous variable $ 0 \le x_{zt} \le 1$ that tracks units of task $z$ assigned to time slot $t$. Assuming each task can be broken down into smaller units and they must sum up to 1. 
You may need a binary variable $ y_{z,t}$ to track time slots alloted to task for the duration. And a continuous var $ \delta$ to track maximum number of task units per time slot.

Then constraints like
$ \sum_t x_{z,t} = 1 $
$ y_{z,t} \le x_{z,t} \le My_{z,t}$
$ \sum_t y_{z,t} = D_z$

<you can have additional constraints for release here. am putting whatever you've posted>

$ \sum_z x_{z,t} \le \delta \ \ \forall t$: getting maximum of units in a time slot

Then min $\delta$

Comment: The cores is essentially how many units of a task we allow to be placed in the same timeslot and we don't have a limit for it but we seek the minimal possible number

Comment: Also doesn't your approach scale pretty bad? As I am interested in something which gives more close to polynomial solution

Comment: Ok edited it. Binary vars will make it NP-Hard but I am not sure if there's any other way to track time slots for task duration.